# Why does openni_tracker not show in Ubuntu software center

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why does openni_tracker not show in Ubuntu software center

```
sudo apt-get install openni_tracker
[sudo] password for viki: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openni_tracker
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114991/why-does-openni_tracker-not-show-in-ubuntu-software-center/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2014-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe there are no binaries for this feature.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2014-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS package names are not the same as the Debian package installed by apt-get. However, they follow a very simple convention: add "ros--" to the beginning, where distro is the ROS distribution (such as "groovy" or "hydro") and then convert any underscore (_) to a dash (-). Thus, you probably want to install ros-hydro-openni-tracker or ros-groovy-openni-tracker.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-01-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2014-01-06**:
That did not work .. but I think it may be because its in hydro-devel. There appears to be no binaries. Yet it is over 2 years old. Is it not supported or is it because it must be compiled on the target machine?